# App install which present in my server during emm device enrollment

Tags: python, json, android-management-api, emm

```
policy_json = {
    "screenCaptureDisabled": False,
    "advancedSecurityOverrides": {
        "developerSettings": "DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_DISABLED"
    },
    "permissionGrants": [
        {"permission": "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "policy": "GRANT"},
        {"permission": "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "policy": "GRANT"}
    ],
    "kioskCustomization": {"systemNavigation": "NAVIGATION_DISABLED"},
    "frpAdminEmails": ["sample@gmail.com", "sample2@gmail.com"],
    "policyEnforcementRules": [
        {
            "blockAction": {
                "blockAfterDays": 0,
                "blockScope": "BLOCK_SCOPE_DEVICE"
            },
            "wipeAction": {
                "wipeAfterDays": 1,
                "preserveFrp": True
            },
            "settingName": "passwordPolicies"
        }
    ],
    "factoryResetDisabled": False,
    "playStoreMode": "BLACKLIST",
    "applications": [
        {
            "packageName": "com.example.app",  
            "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
            "lockTaskAllowed": True,
            "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
            "managedConfiguration": {
                "url": app_url
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my policy i am using to install a app which is present in my live server.Device is enrolling currectly but the app is not showing in the device. Please suggest me with the currect way.
Thank you in aadvance